# Is there a way to update a mysql table with php without knowing the values beforehand?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following code to grab my mysql table rows and column headers without knowing them beforehand and formatting the table. I am creating a service that allows users to generate tables and save them into a mysql database so I need to be able to retrieve the data this way.

I am trying to update and edit he table and make it live. Usually this is done with each value being updated individually knowing all the column values.

This is my code to get the values

```
<?php
 try {
 $con= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx', "", "");
 $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM ``
 //first pass just gets the column names
 print "<table>";
 $result = $con->query($query);
 //return only the first row (we only need field names)
 $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 print " <tr>";
 foreach ($row as $field => $value){
 print " <th>$field</th>";
 } // end foreach
 print " </tr>";
 //second query gets the data
 $data = $con->query($query);
 $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 foreach($data as $row){
 print " <tr>";
 foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
 print " <td>$value</td>";
 } // end field loop
 print " </tr>";
 } // end record loop
 print "</table>";
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
 } // end try
?>
```

I am trying to use the following to update the values:

```
foreach($_POST as $name=>$value)
{
    if($value != '')
{
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
}
```

However, the row values are not updating at all. Is there any way I can scan the table and update the values each time a value is edited?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. You're going to run into all kinds of vulnerabilities and permission based problems

Comment: This is a locally hosted site that is password protected. Only those on the LAN can use the service.

Comment: Have you considered maybe storing the data as a json object in a single uniform column in your database? If I understand your question correctly, what you're trying to do is essentially outside the realm of relational databases.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is similar to the mysql for excel plugin. It's a plugin that gets all the mysql data on excel and then allows you to make changes and commit that change into the database. I want to do the same except in an html table format.

Comment: You've left out the rest of the line starting with `$query =`. It's causing all sorts of syntax highlighting problems in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to perform the query twice. You can use the `columnCount()` and `getColumnMeta()` methods to get all the column names.

```
$result = $con->query($query);
$colCount = $result->columnCount();
echo "<tr>";
for ($i = 0; $i < colCount; $i++) {
    $name = $result->getColumnMeta()["name"];
    echo "<th>$name</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
```